How to select rows that display some type of pattern in Python
I am looking to extract rows from my dataset based on a pattern like condition. The condition I'm looking for is finding periods in a battery's charging history where it discharged from 100-0% without charging in between.
For example, in this dataset below I would be interested in a function that would only return timestamp of 7 to 12 as it contains a full discharge of the battery.



timestamp
Charge level (%)




1
50


2
55


3
40


4
60


5
80


6
100


7
100


8
85


9
60


10
55


11
40


12
0


13
20



The approach I have tried is to use the loc function in Pandas to look for rows with a charge level of 0% and then backtrack until I reach a row with a charge level of 100%.
But I am struggling with the backtracking part in this approach.

[Code updated according to comments]
The idea I use is to keep only the rows with 0 and 100 and the final rows of interest will be the ones with 100 followed by 0. [after checking with .diff(1) that the values are monotonically decreasing]
I also updated your example to include some more difficult cases like when it start discharging and then start charging before it was fully discharged [or fully discharged].
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', None):
    display(df.T)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
time    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25
level   20  0   40  60  80  100 100 85  60  40  40  0   100 20  20  55  100 10  100 0   100 20  40  0   20

df["diff1"] = df["level"].diff(1)
df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
res = df.copy()

mask =((res["level"] == 100) | (res["level"] == 0)) 
res = res.loc[mask]

mask1 = (res["level"] == 100) & (res["level"].shift(-1) == 0)
mask2 = (res["level"] == 0) & (res["level"].shift(1) == 100)
res = res.loc[mask1 | mask2, ["level"]]

    level
time    
7   100
12  0
19  100
20  0
21  100
24  0

# Get the start and end of all the segments having levels [100, ..., 0]
t_start, t_end = res[res["level"] == 100].index, res[res["level"] == 0].index
 
# Among all the segments keep only the ones with level monotonically decreasing
idx = [(t_start[i], t_end[i]) for i in range(len(t_start)) 
       if (df.loc[t_start[i]+1:t_end[i], "diff1"] <= 0).all()]
print(idx)  # All resulting groups with (start_time, end_time)

[(7, 12), (19, 20)]

# Example to get the sum of all the levels in result group n°0 (idx[0] ie (7, 12))
gp0 = df.loc[idx[0][0]:idx[0][1], ["level"]]
display(gp0)

    level
time    
7   100
8   85
9   60
10  40
11  40
12  0

print(f"The sum of levels is {sum(gp0['level'])}.")
The sum of levels is 325.


This is an elegant solution. As a follow up, I am also wondering what would be a good method to find the sum of values of in a column in the range of the full discharge. For example, the first discharge is from time 7-12, so I would like to know the sum of time in that period, which would be (7+8+9+10+11+12) in this example.

@K.Sx0000 This solution will also include cases where the charge occurs between going from 100 to 0 in the answer. For example, it will extract cases where 100->20->40->0.

@PandaKim you were right! I updated the code to take your & OP comment into account.

@PandaKim Thank you for pointing that out, in reality my data set has very few instances where the charge goes from 100 to 0 without interruption, so I was satisfied with the original solution.

Code
c1 = df['Charge level (%)'].eq(100)
c2 = df['Charge level (%)'].eq(0)
grp = (c1 | c2.shift()).cumsum()
c3 = df.groupby(grp)['Charge level (%)'].diff().ge(0).groupby(grp).transform('any')
out = df[c1.groupby(grp).transform('any') & c2.groupby(grp).transform('any') & ~c3]

out
    timestamp  Charge level (%)
6           7               100
7           8                85
8           9                60
9          10                55
10         11                40
11         12                 0


If you have multiple bands and want to separate them, create grp column.
out2 = out.assign(
    grp=grp[grp.index.isin(out.index)].rank(method='dense')
).astype('int')

chk with new example
new example
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "timestamp": range(1, 23),
    "Charge level (%)": [50, 55, 100, 60, 0, 100, 70, 20,  100, 85, 60, 40, 50, 0, 20, 100, 85, 60, 55, 40, 0, 20],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out2:
    timestamp  Charge level (%)  grp
2           3               100    1
3           4                60    1
4           5                 0    1
15         16               100    2
16         17                85    2
17         18                60    2
18         19                55    2
19         20                40    2
20         21                 0    2


You could use numba to vectorize a loop logic.
If you want the start/end indices:
import numba

@numba.jit()
def find_discharge(a):
    start = None
    prev = np.inf
    out_idx = []
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if x == 100:
            start = i
        elif x == 0 and start is not None:
            out_idx.append([start, i])
            start = None
        elif x > prev:
            start = None
    return out_idx
            
out = find_discharge(df['Charge level (%)'].to_numpy())
# array([[ 6, 11]])

# for timestamps
idx = np.array(find_discharge(df['Charge level (%)'].to_numpy()))
out = df['timestamp'].to_numpy()[idx]
# array([[ 7, 12]])

If you want a mask:
import numba

@numba.jit()
def find_discharge(a):
    start = None
    prev = np.inf
    out_mask = np.full(len(a), False)
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        if x == 100:
            start = i
        elif x == 0 and start is not None:
            out_mask[start:i+1] = True
            start = None
        elif x > prev:
            start = None
    return out_mask
            
out = find_discharge(df['Charge level (%)'].to_numpy())
# array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
#         True,  True,  True, False])


You could use the following:
a = df['Charge level (%)']
(df.groupby((a.shift().eq(0) | a.eq(100)).cumsum())['Charge level (%)']\
  .transform(lambda x: x.diff().dropna().lt(0).all() and x.size > 1)\
  .pipe(lambda x: df.loc[x]))

Out: 
    timestamp  Charge level (%)
6           7               100
7           8                85
8           9                60
9          10                55
10         11                40
11         12                 0


Steps for an approach to solve this problem:

Find all rows where the charge level is 0%.
For each row with 0%, backtrack to find the previous row with 100%.
If you find a sequence of rows between these two timestamps where the charge level is strictly decreasing, it indicates a full discharge.

Function for this approach:
import pandas as pd

def find_discharge_periods(df):
    discharge_periods = []
    # Iterate over rows where charge level is 0%
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.iloc[i]['Charge level (%)'] == 0:
            # Backtrack to find a row with 100% charge level
            for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
                if df.iloc[j]['Charge level (%)'] == 100:
                    # Now check if the values between the 100% and 0% are strictly decreasing
                    is_decreasing = True
                    for k in range(j, i+1):
                        if k > j and df.iloc[k]['Charge level (%)'] >= df.iloc[k-1]['Charge level (%)']:
                            is_decreasing = False
                            break
                    if is_decreasing:
                        discharge_periods.append(df.iloc[j]['timestamp'])
                        discharge_periods.append(df.iloc[i]['timestamp'])
                    break

    return discharge_periods

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'timestamp': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
        'Charge level (%)': [50, 55, 40, 60, 80, 100, 100, 85, 60, 55, 40, 0, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Find discharge periods
discharge_periods = find_discharge_periods(df)
print(discharge_periods)

For the given example dataset it will give the following output:
[7, 12]

This indicates that the battery discharged from 100% at timestamp 7 to 0% at timestamp 12 without any charge in between. Let me know if this works for you.

You can solve this by using Pandas to identify the start and end points of the discharge (100% to 0%) and check if the charge levels decrease continuously between them. Here's a solution:
import pandas as pd

# Your dataset
data = {
    "timestamp": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
    "Charge level (%)": [50, 55, 40, 60, 80, 100, 100, 85, 60, 55, 40, 0, 20],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Find starting points (100%) and ending points (0%)
starts = df[df["Charge level (%)"] == 100].index
ends = df[df["Charge level (%)"] == 0].index

valid_ranges = []

# Check for valid discharge sequences
for start in starts:
    for end in ends:
        if start < end:  # Ensure a valid sequence
            charge_levels = df.loc[start:end, "Charge level (%)"]
            if all(charge_levels.diff().dropna() <= 0):  # Check if levels are decreasing
                valid_ranges.append((df.loc[start, "timestamp"], df.loc[end, "timestamp"]))

print("Discharge periods from 100% to 0%:", valid_ranges)

Output
This will give you:
Discharge periods from 100% to 0%: [(7, 12)]

This approach loops through the potential start and end points and validates that the charge levels decrease continuously. Let me know if you'd like more help!

if you have multiple rows at 100% and multiple rows at 0%, you might find overlapping or very short sequences and also You checking for strict 100% and 0% points. If you wanted to handle scenarios where the battery might have been at, say, 99.8% or 1% it wont work
